# mysql update query check whether data updated or matches

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE cab_details SET travel_company_person_name='$user_role', driver_name='$driver_name' , driver_phone_no='$driver_phone' , vehicle_name='$vehicle_name' , vehicle_no='$vehicle_no' , starting_kms = '$starting_kms' , region='$region', cd_comments='$comments' WHERE travel_id='$id' AND ((travel_id NOT IN (SELECT cancel_customer.ctravel_id FROM cancel_customer WHERE ctravel_id='$id'))   AND travel_id NOT IN (SELECT tcc_travel_id FROM travel_company_cancel WHERE tcc_travel_id='$id' AND tcc_travel_cancel_company='$travel_company'))
```

In the above sql query, the mysql_affected_rows() returns 0 when the data matches the existing one and also when the conditions doesn't satisfy.
I want to alert the user as "No change in data" or "Condition not satisfied".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value
>   is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that
>   mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows
>   matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the
>   query.

Since you can't differentiate based on the return value of mysql_affected_rows(), you can run a query to test if the record exists first for the WHERE condition of the query.

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM cab_details
WHERE travel_id='$id' AND 
((travel_id NOT IN (SELECT cancel_customer.ctravel_id FROM cancel_customer WHERE ctravel_id='$id')) AND 
travel_id NOT IN (SELECT tcc_travel_id FROM travel_company_cancel WHERE tcc_travel_id='$id' AND tcc_travel_cancel_company='$travel_company'))
```

If the number of rows returned is 0, return "Condition not satisfied"

If the number of rows > 0, do the update and test for mysql_affected_rows() which if =0, then return "No change in data"